# http:// to https://www. redirection doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, redirect, https

I've got the same problem, exactly - when entering, for example, **example.com**, (so = http://example.com), it would be redirected to https://www.example.com, otherwise the page will not be shown. But the redirection doesn't go. Here's the last solution I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't help. More exactly, it only helps in normal browser windows of Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Google Chrome, but not in incognito windows. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Ignoring the redirect for a moment... what happens currently when requesting `example.com`? Is it resolving to your site? (The "page should still be shown".)

Comment: "it only helps in normal browser windows of Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Google Chrome, but not in incognito windows." - Except that doesn't really make sense. Assuming you have a _new_ incognito session then it would suggest you are seeing a cached response/redirect in "normal" browsers. But the rule you've posted is "correct" (for most servers). What do you mean by "the redirection doesn't go"? Nothing happens? Or do you get an error?

Comment: @MrWhite it shows the "internal server error" wenn only entering the domain name without the https://www or even without the www.

Comment: "it shows the "internal server error"" - You made no mention of an "Internal Server Error" in your question? (You need to check your server's error log for the details of this error.) However, I can't see how the directives you've posted would relate to this error? Or is this what happens with these directives removed (as requested in my first comment)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or this (will work for any domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why would this work and the directives in the question not? (They are essentially the same.) However, you've removed the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, so this won't actually do the same thing.